# RVM problems installing ruby 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I did `rvm get stable`

Then I tried to install ruby 2.0.0

```
$ **rvm install 2.0.0** 
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for smf, might require sudo password.
Installing SM Framework.
Error running 'requirements_smf_install_sm',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/smf_install.log

$ **cat /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/smf_install.log**
[2013-03-28 20:58:11] requirements_smf_install_sm
SMF Framework support is only intended for RailsInstaller, please use Homebrew integration instead.
```

The error log is not very helpful. I am on Mac OS X Mountain Lion.
Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running

```
brew update
```

If you don't have brew installed there is a good guide here to doing the whole installation process, you can ignore the 1.9.3 stuff and replace it with 2.0.0

http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

Comment: Aye, I had the same problem, and updating `brew` fixed it right up for me.

Comment: I updated brew and installed "brew install libksba" as said in the tutorial that you sent. What else do I need to install?

Comment: What happens when you run `rvm install 2.0.0` now?

Comment: I solved it by doing rvm install 2.0.0 --autolibs=brew. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Tony absolutely. Had the same problem and this solved it for me too. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

It's because RVM was set to use a different library system: SMF.  You need to set RVM to use brew instead.  Here is page on rvm autolibs
https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs/

Use `rvm autolibs show` to see what your current setting is and if you are using brew, you can change it with  `rvm autolibs brew`

Comment: Thanks to a reviewer who corrected my commands. Strange that 3 admins rejected it.

Comment: rvm autolibs macports works quite well too, if you use ports instead of homebrew :)